# why two option in javascript working at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to show partial view action ReqItem when i will get a value which greater then zero in OdrQty, it will show partial view ReqItem. Otherwise it will not show. This script working but problem is, it is not dividing total/2.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#OdrQty').blur(function () {
                var total = $('#OdrQty').val();

                $("#Qty1").val(total / 2);
                $("#Qty2").val(total / 2);
                $("#Qty3").val((total * 0.04) / 20);
                $("#Qty4").val((total * 0.07) / 20);

                if (total > 0) {
                    $("#ordDetail").empty();
                    $.get('/Ordering/ReqItem/', function (data) {
                        $("#ordDetail").html(data);
                    });
                };

            //alert("total:" + total);

        });
}
```

When i am not using some code it is working divide code. This code is

```
$('#OdrQty').blur(function () {
    var total = $('#OdrQty').val();

    $("#Qty1").val(total / 2);
    $("#Qty2").val(total / 2);
    $("#Qty3").val((total * 0.04) / 20);
    $("#Qty4").val((total * 0.07) / 20);


});
```

In my view I am using This code For Viewing partial view...

```
@*  @Html.Action("reqitem") *@
    <div id="ordDetail">


</div>
```

SO how i can get those data same time and working properly. please experts help me.

Comment: Can you `alert(total);` and see if it contains any value?

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger Yes both of the time it contains same value of OdrQty

Answer (score 0):

In your if block there is a semicolon after curly bracket. remove it and check it again your code is fine.

Comment: if (total > 0) {
                    $("#ordDetail").empty();
                    $.get('/Ordering/ReqItem/', function (data) {
                        $("#ordDetail").html(data); 

                    });
                };
remove the last semicolon

Comment: @MNAH The code works if you do not write the `if (total > 0) {` block right? If so, then as Krishna pointed out the semi-colon at the end of the block must be the error. Is there anything outputted in `#ordDetail`?

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger when i removed the semicolon totally my script is not working and not showing anything error in code. so i think my false is not here.

Comment: If you have given the whole script block than in last closing bracket and semicolon is missing. I have just created the same scenario as per your code. check it http://jsfiddle.net/U9gXx/4/